# Example of jScrollPane and Tabs, almost working together

Tags: tabs, jscrollpane, jquery

I would like the scroll bar (from jScrollPane) to show up with every tab (from Soh Tanaka). Currently, it shows up for the first tab, but it falls back to the browser default for the second, third, fourth tabs…

**See my live example here: [jScrollPane and Tabs, almost working together](http://christopherhildebrand.com/test/furniture.php)**

How can I get the scroll bar to display on every tab? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
                verticalDragMinHeight: 20,
                verticalDragMaxHeight: 20,
                horizontalDragMinWidth: 20,
                horizontalDragMaxWidth: 20
    });
```

});

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

//When page loads...
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-initialise jScrollPane after you have shown each tab. A simple example here:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/invisibles.html

In your case you could try:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn().jScrollPane(); //Fade in the active ID content and apply jScrollPane
    return false;
});
```

(I somehow posted this answer to [the wrong question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273991/how-to-make-the-jquery-ui-draggable-auto-scrolling-with-jscrollpane/4278301#4278301) yesterday - so sorry for the delay in answering!)

Comment: Thanks Vitch for your help. I've setup a test page with your code included, but it's not working either... here's the link: http://christopherhildebrand.com/test/furniture-test.php Any other suggestion? // Should I rebuild the entire page following the link you provided?

Comment: Can you provide a URL to the test page?

Comment: If I visit that page I see this error in Firebug when I click "blocks": `$(activeTab).fadeIn().jScrollPane is not a function`. Maybe try putting this on the line before and viewing with Firebug's console open: `console.log(activeTab, $(activeTab), $(activeTab).jScrollPane... Actually, looking at your code, it appears you are using `jQuery.noConflict` - I'm not sure why. But you could try replacing $ with jQuery....

Comment: I failed miserably. I had to abort this approach for now. thanks for the help.